# Can you create a class with the __init__ method but not specify the total arguments?

Tags: python

For example, if I wanted to create a class called "**Clinical_triads**" could I include *args as a parameter to indicate an arbitrary number of arguments? Would I then include this as an argument variable?

```
class Clinical_triads:
""" Clinical S&Sx of medical triads """

    def __init__(self, SSx_1, SSx_2, SSx_3, *args):  
    """ Initialize SSx_1, SSx_2, SSx_3 of clinical signs """
        self.SSx_1 = SSx_1
        self.SSx_2 = SSx_2
        self.SSx_3 = SSx_3
        self.additional_SSx = args  # is this variable needed?

    def SSx1(self):
    """ Print the first clinical sign or symptom"""
        return f"{self.SSx_1.title()}"

    def SSx2(self):
    """ Print the second clinical sign or symptom"""
        return f"{self.SSx_2.title()}"

    def SSx3(self):
    """ Print the third clinical sign or symptom"""
        return f"{self.SSx_3.title()}"
```

Comment: *Could* you? Yes. *Would* you? That's going to depend on the context. In this case `additional_SSx` doesn't seem to get used, so what's the point of it?

Comment: If you were going to do this, you should call the parameter something like `*additional_SSx` so that the parameter hint shown in IDEs gives the user some idea of what those additional parameters actually mean.  It's the leading asterisk that makes a variable-length parameter, the specific name `*args` is traditional but has no inherent meaning.  But if you were going to do this, you should probably use it for *all* of your SSx's, rather than special-casing the first three.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems like you want to specify 3 key symptoms ("triad").  If you want to use `*args` to be able to pass, remember, and reuse additional (variable number) symptoms, then definitely **yes** you need to store them as an attribute of `Clinical_triads` (where they will be stored as a `tuple`).  If you pass `*args` to `__init__()` without doing so, that just means you can pass as many arguments to `Clinical_triads` without causing an `TypeError`, but arguments beyond the 3 specified keywords would be pointless and irretrievable!

As said in the comments, you aren't doing anything with the additional arguments right now, but (e.g.) you could say add a method for printing additional symptoms:

```
def additional_symptoms(self):
    for i, symp in enumerate(self.additional_SSx):
        print('Additional symptom #{0}: {1}'.format(i+1,symp))
```

I think there are several similar options, and you can probably think about what is best for what you want to achieve.  You could also just have another keyword argument for "additional symptoms" which defaults to an empty array.  Or you could only use `*args` and infer their importance (and assign attributes like `SSx_#`) by the order they were passed.

But yes, using `*args` or `**kwargs` in a class works, and can be useful.  Here's an example a la the typical explanation for using `*args` in function definitions:

```
class Math_Whiz:
    """Perform math on a buncha numbers"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.nums = args
        
    def sum(self):
        return sum(self.nums)
    
    def avg(self):
        return sum(self.nums)/len(self.nums)
```

I think it just depends what information you want to associate with the class and how you want to be able to retrieve it.